# Android app even on the latest version crashes when TLS 1.0 and 1.1 is disabled at the server

Tags: android, tls1.2

I recently disabled support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 at server-side and all Android apps stopped to work.  I know Android 4 and below don't support TSL 1.2 or higher but even the app running on Android 10 stopped working.  The stack trace on the phone shows TLS issues.  Apps installed on iphones see no issues.  When we enable the support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 Android app works fine on all Android phones but then the security audit of the server goes down.   Is there something in Android OS where the support for TLS 1.2 can be enabled?

Comment: It was due to the certificate chain.   iOS was able to pull an intermediate certificate,  Android didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently and reading about it in the internet austerity there could be multiple places in your current where the call might fail, even on recent Android versions. However you can do a two major steps to make sure your application is ready for TLS 1.2:

1. Make sure to use Google Play Services and enable the security service (`com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller`). You have to do this in your code *before* you create any HttpClient resource (otherwise they will use an older security specification) Having something like this in the `onCreate` of your main activity should work nicely:

   ```
   try {
       ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
       Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Google Play Services Installed");
   } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
       GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
               .showErrorNotification(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode());
       Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
   } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
       Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
   }
   ```

   It's important to have this run *before* any http client is created otherwise they will not have TLS 1.2 support
2. Make sure TLS 1.2 is enabled in your HttpClient. Some of the clients have a default configuration that does not have TLS 1.2 enabled. For example for OkHttp you should create the following SocketFactory:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

import okhttp3.CipherSuite;
import okhttp3.ConnectionSpec;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.TlsVersion;

/**
 * Enables TLS v1.2 when creating SSLSockets.
 * <p/>
 * For some reason, android supports TLS v1.2 from API 16, but enables it by
 * default only from API 20.
 * @link https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html
 * @see SSLSocketFactory
 */
public class Tls12SocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    private static final String[] TLS_V12_ONLY = {"TLSv1.2"};

    final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

    public Tls12SocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory base) {
        this.delegate = base;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket patch(Socket s) {
        if (s instanceof SSLSocket) {
            ((SSLSocket) s).setEnabledProtocols(TLS_V12_ONLY);
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static final CipherSuite[] APPROVED_CIPHER_SUITES = new CipherSuite[] {
            // TLSv1.3
            CipherSuite.TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            CipherSuite.TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_AES_256_CCM_8_SHA256,

            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,

            // Note that the following cipher suites are all on HTTP/2's bad cipher suites list. We'll
            // continue to include them until better suites are commonly available. For example, none
            // of the better cipher suites listed above shipped with Android 4.4 or Java 7.
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
    };

    public static OkHttpClient.Builder enableTls12OnPreLollipop(OkHttpClient.Builder client) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                sc.init(null, null, null);

                client.sslSocketFactory(new Tls12SocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()));

                ConnectionSpec cs = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                        .cipherSuites(APPROVED_CIPHER_SUITES)
                        .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_3, TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                        .supportsTlsExtensions(true)
                        .build();

                List<ConnectionSpec> specs = new ArrayList<>();
                specs.add(cs);
                client.connectionSpecs(specs);

                Log.i("OkHttpTLSCompat", "TLS 1.2 enabled");
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Log.e("OkHttpTLSCompat", "Error while setting TLS 1.2", exc);
            }
        }

        return client;
    }

    public static OkHttpClient returnClient() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .followRedirects(true)
                .followSslRedirects(true)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .cache(null)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return enableTls12OnPreLollipop(client).build();
    }
}
```

And then do `Tls12SocketFactory.returnClient()` when you need one

It's important that you need to have both enabled! Without the Google Play security services you won't have TLS 1.2 support on older Android devices regardless of what http library you are using. And it's also important to make sure TLS is enabled (and potentially enforced) in the HttpClient as well.

Also let me reiterate that it's important to load up the Google Play updates before you create any http client. It took me a while to debug this recently as in my code some of the libraries have been initialized before I put in the Google Play code  and hence they did not receive TLS 1.2 support

Comment: Thanks.  It is strange.  The security layer should be in the OS and should not require developers to worry about it.

Comment: The security layer is part of the OS but it allows updates from the code to allow new features to be running from the application side, so new apps can still run under phones with Android 4. New phones should have these enabled already by default (and the code above is just a no-op on them) but there might be vendors with outdated implementations. From what I've read Samsung is one of the offenders